# Is it correct to say thanks to all of you?

Tags: phrases

I've heard people saying thanks to all of you. Is it correct to say thanks to all of you? I personally think thanks all of you is better than that. I'm confused about these two phrases. May I know which one is correct or both are correct?

Answer (score 1):

"Thanks, all of you" requires a pause to be correct. "Thanks" is actually a noun, but it is used as an abbreviation for "thank you." It is not completely interchangeable with "thank you," though.

"Thanks to all of you," however, is correct. You can think of it in the back of your mind as short for "I'm sending my thanks to all of you."

Comment: @iser178049 Yes, "Thanks to all of you" is correct. I'm saying that without the pause "Thanks all of you" is not correct.